# Setting initial values of a form via an API call

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, formik

In my React game, I use a React library called Formik for a form.

In it, you set the initial values for the form like this:

```
<Formik
    initialValues={{
        characterClasses: ["1", "3", "9"],
        race: "Elf",
        name: "Derolt",
        age: "84",
        
        ..etc
```

But now, I'm in a situtation where I want to load the initial values from an API call.

So I created this:

```
const fetchGameCharData = async (gameId) => {
    const game = await axios("api/games/" + gameId);
    // return the result
    return game;
};
```

My problem is, I can't figure out how to use the above fetch method to actually populate the initialValues part that Formik uses.

Has anyone ever done this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use [conditional-rendering](https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html) approach.

Load your form only after you get the response from API call. Show `loading...` or a custom `spinner` until you get API response.

> With this approach, your form directly load with `initial values` without any flickering of having no values at first load and values comes up in a flash as a result of API response.

#### Edit

```js
// In your state add two values like
initialValues: [],
isValueLoded: false

...

// Make your API call in `componentDidMount`
componentDidMount() {
    // Call your API
    fetchGameCharData(....).then(res => {
        this.setState({ isValueLoded: true, initialValues: res.values});
    }).catch(err => ....);
}

....

// In your render method
render() {

    return !this.state.isValueLoded ?
       (<div>Loading...</div>) : (
        <Formki
          values={this.state.initialValues}
         ....
         />
    );
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand.  So I have my API call...how does that run and automatically load into InitialValues?  Thanks!

Comment: Updated sample code for you. You can improvise based on your requirement. @yash answer helps you in case you are using `function component`. Approach is same as above.

Comment: Pass `enableReinitialize` prop to Formik also.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using class component:

```
componentDidMount() {
    this.fetchGame();
}

async fetchGame() {
    const game = await fetchGameCharData(GAME_ID);
    this.setState({ game });
}
...
// in render method
const { game } = this.state;
...
<Formik
    initialValues={game}
...
```

If you are using functional component:

```
const { game, setGame } = useState();

useEffect(async () => {
    const game = await fetchGameCharData(GAME_ID);
    setGame(game);
}, []);

...
// in return
<Formik
    initialValues={{
        characterClasses: ["1", "3", "9"],
        race: "Elf",
        name: "Derolt",
        age: "84",
        ...
    }}
    values={game}
...
```

Just make sure to render the `Formik` only when the `game` is available.
Otherwise it will be error as `initialValues` require an object has all properties needed for the form.

Comment: Thanks but this is a functional component that uses React hooks...

Comment: that case is added as well

Comment: One thing that I don't get is that the Formik documentation sets value on individual items...like... name: "Fred", age: "30", PlayerClass: "Wizard".....etc

Comment: each property is presenting a form control?

Comment: actually i am not very sure what you mean about the above comment, but you could add the link to the documentation here

Comment: well each property value is assigned to the appropriate form control

Comment: Thanks...this page has a very simple example: https://formik.org/docs/api/formik

Comment: i think `values` will be better than `initialValues` for your case.

Comment: so ... values={game} ?

Comment: `initialValues` is a required field, so you may predefine it with all form controls. and `values` will update your form as the api response arrives. I updated the functional component in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

This is an example for your problem :

```js
const [officeInfo, setOfficeInfo] = useState({})  
async function fetchOfficeInfo() {
    try {
      const response = await iaxios.get(url)
      setOfficeInfo(response.data)
    
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error)
    }
  }
 useEffect(() => {
    fetchOfficeInfo()
  }, [])
  ....
  
  <Formik
  enableReinitialize={true}
  initialValues={officeInfo}
  ...
  />
```