# antd form is not rendered when initialValues changed

Tags: reactjs, forms, next.js, antd, next-auth

I am getting data from useSession() hook and use it for my initialValues. When I check my component everything is okey. But when user refresh the page on ui, my values cleared on ui. But I can see initialValues which is updated on console. My component related code parts is:

```
import {
  Form,
} from "antd";
import { User } from "@/types/User";
import { useSession } from "next-auth/react";

const ProfileTab = () => {
  const { data: session, update } = useSession();
  const user = session?.user as User;

  const initialValues = {
    name: user?.name,
    locale: user?.locale,
    avatar: user?.avatar,
  };

  // At first, I tried to this useEffect to render Form component. But it didn't work. I saw updated values in the console but the form didn't render with the updated values.
  // useEffect(() => {
  //   form.setFieldsValue({
  //     name: user?.name,
  //     locale: user?.locale,
  //   });
  // }, [session, form]);

  const onFinish = (values: FieldType) => {
    let putValues: PutValues = {
      name: values.name,
      locale: values.locale,
    };

    api.client
      .put("user", putValues)
      .then((res) => {
        notification.success({
          message: "Profile updated",
        });

        if (user) {
          // This function updates the session
          update({
            ...session,
            user: {
              ...user,
              name: res.data.data.name,
              avatar: res.data.data.avatar,
              locale: res.data.data.locale,
            },
          });
        }
      })
      .catch((res) => {...});
  };

  const onFinishFailed = () => {...};

  const customizeRequiredMark = () => {...}

  const onAvatarChange = () => {...}

  return (
    <div className="p-8">
      {contextHolder}
      <Form
        key={JSON.stringify(initialValues)} // This is required to render the form again when the initialValues change
        initialValues={initialValues}
        labelCol={{ span: 4 }}
        wrapperCol={{ span: 8 }}
        colon={false}
        layout="horizontal"
        requiredMark={customizeRequiredMark}
        onFinish={onFinish}
        onFinishFailed={onFinishFailed}
      >

        <Form.Item<FieldType>
          name="name"
          label={<Label label="Name" required />}
          labelAlign="left"
          rules={[{ required: true, message: "Name field is required" }]}
        >
          <Input size="large" />
        </Form.Item>

        <Form.Item<FieldType>
          name="locale"
          label={<Label label="Locale" />}
          labelAlign="left"
        >
          <Select
            size="large"
            options={[
              { value: "ar", label: "Arabic" },
              { value: "en", label: "English" },
              { value: "tr", label: "Türkçe" },
            ]}
          />
        </Form.Item>

        <Form.Item wrapperCol={{ offset: 4, span: 8 }}>
          <Button
            loading={saving}
            type="primary"
            htmlType="submit"
            size="large"
            onClick={() => setSaving(true)}
          >
            Save
          </Button>
        </Form.Item>
      </Form>
    </div>
  );
};

export default ProfileTab;
```

At first, I read and tried this suggestions. [stackoverflow.com/61422607](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61422607/update-antd-form-if-initialvalue-is-changed) but useEffect() hook was not solve my problem. Then I tried to use `key` prop my  component. It solve my problem but I am not sure it is best practise.
Could anyone provide insights or alternative solutions to ensure that my form retains the correct initial values even after a page refresh?

Comment: initialValues only works for first render. If you want to set values, use `form.setFieldsValue` or `form.setFieldValue`. `const [form] = Form.useForm();` and connect this form with `<Form form={form} ..>...`

Comment: Thank you so much!! @MuhammadNoumanRafique . I understood my fault is I didn't connect form to <Form> component as `<Form form={form} ..>...`

Answer (score 0):

At the bottom of [Form.Item](https://ant.design/components/form#formitem) section, the documentation mentions:

> Note that `initialValues` cannot be updated by `setState` dynamically, you should use `setFieldsValue` in that situation.

Besides, you forget the pass the `form` control instance created by `Form.useForm()` to the `<Form />` component. Then you can call the [instance methods](https://ant.design/components/form#forminstance).